# plotting multiple graphs on the same figure in Octave

Tags: octave

I'm trying to plot multiple graphs on a single figure in Octave. Here is my code: these graphs represents the decrease of the cost function on each iteration of gradient decent:

```
% Init Theta and Run Gradient Descent 
theta = zeros(3, 1);
[theta, J_history] = gradientDescentMulti(X, y, zeros(3, 1), alpha, num_iters);
[theta1,J1]=gradientDescentMulti(X, y, zeros(3, 1), 0.05, num_iters);
[theta3,J3]=gradientDescentMulti(X, y, zeros(3, 1), 0.03, num_iters);
% Plot the convergence graph
figure;
plot(1:numel(J_history), J_history, 'g', 'LineWidth', 2);
hold on;

plot(1:50, J2, 'r'); 
plot(1:50, J3, 'b');

xlabel('Number of iterations');
ylabel('Cost J');
```

However, when I run the codes, I got only one graph on the figure without even the labels, The best I was able to d was to put two graph on the same figure:

[image]

Is there something wrong with my codes?

Comment: Do you get any error messages? `plot(1:50, J2, 'r'); ` would fail if `J2` doesn't have 50 elements. We cannot reproduce your code because `gradientDescentMulti` is undefined, as are most of the variables you use. See [mre], and try to create one. I recommend that you make some arrays with `rand` that have the same sizes as the stuff you're trying to plot, so you don't need to bother us with `gradientDescentMulti` and all the unrelated stuff.

Comment: Are you talking about [subplot](https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.0/Multiple-Plots-on-One-Page.html)?